# Use html5 <detail> & <summary> tag change display to flex does not work in ios webview

Tags: html, css, webview

I put the web into the IOS app as a webview.
When I use the `<detail>` tag of html 5, I want to change it's display to flex not block,in web it can work  but it cannot work on the phone

This is my code, is there any mistake?

```css
 
  details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
  }

  details{
      width:100%;
  }
  
  details summary {
    width: 100%;
    /* padding: 0.5rem 0; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
  }
  details summary:after {
    content: "click me";
    color: black;
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 200ms linear;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <details style="display: flex; ">
    <summary class="d-flex">
             <div class="mr-3 w-75">
                 <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mr-3 w-75">
                 <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">date</p>
                 <span class="t-12">time</span>
            </div>
   </summary>
            <p>
            <pre class="d-inline">content</pre>
            </p>
 </details>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is documented here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-9

The following workaround was proposed there:

> The simple solution to this problem is to use a wrapper element that can be a flex container (like a ) directly inside of the element that can't. Demos 9.1.b and 9.2.b show workaround for the  and  elements, respectively.

In your case you should wrap your elements that should be displayed as `flex` in a wrapper element like a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue: the flex properties were not working with the summary tags in a WebView, otherwise working on a normal browser. The only workaround I found was to recreate the details-summary tag functionality with javascript by changing the display property.

```js
document.querySelector('.summary').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let collapsible = this.nextElementSibling
  collapsible.classList.toggle('d-block')
})
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
}

.collapsible {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.summary {
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 0.5rem 0; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  list-style: none;
}

.summary::after {
  content: "click me";
  color: black;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="d-flex summary">
    <div class="mr-3 w-75">
      <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mr-3 w-75">
      <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">date</p>
      <span class="t-12">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible">
    <pre class="d-inline">content</pre>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have meet same issue.when i use flex in ssummary tag.i think a good way is not to use flex instead of using other css layout ways.

```
position:absolute;
```

use trandition css to manage our child